# Посоветуйте литературу по шейдерам

Tags: книги, шейдеры

Привет всем!
Хочу понять, что такое шейдеры, зачем они, и как их готовить, но не могу понять, с какой стороны к ним подойти.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, литературу. Желательно, для совсем тупых, в которой очень понятным языком объясняют про шейдеры? ;]

Comment: как вы самокритичны однако же

Comment: @DreamChild, просто очень хочется понять, что это такое, и с чем их едят. Графику прогал очень мало, спросить не у кого особо. Потому и поинтересовался здесь. Может кто посоветует чего)